# Подскажите либу для работы с файлами формата docx

Tags: javascript, поиск-библиотек

Есть доковский документ, где в определенные места мне нужно вставлять текст, из инпутов, которые я создал в индекс.хтмл. Слышал что есть какая та либа...которая на место крестиков вставляет текст введенный клиентом из инпутов, или что-то похожее. Есть хорошая библиотека https://docx.js.org/#/, ну она не подходит, так как она создает текст на основе инпутов, а мне нужно работать уже с готовым текстовым документом, и вставлять текст в определенные места

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, это то, что вам нужно: https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater

А вообще, для работы с текстовыми файлами в таком режиме я бы советовал изучить LaTeX

Comment: Да, спасибо. Эта либа то, что мне нужно. Только хотелось бы, чтобы в текстовый документ еще вставлялись картинки. А там этот модуль платный, существует ли бесплатный модуль вставки картинок в текстовый документ?
docxtemplater-image-module-free
вот вроде бы есть...но у меня не получается его поставить